# ¿Cómo cargar una lista enlazada en C?

Tags: c, lista, insert, imprimir

¿Cómo puedo cargar datos a una lista enlazada? Los datos provienen de un **tda.h** que los almacena.

Los cargo, pero el problema es que cuando los quiero mostrar, no muestra nada. Traté de muchas maneras, hasta revisando si era problema de punteros, pero sigue sin mostrar. Todas las funciones de la lista y su codificación se hacen en **lista.h**

El código de la función que carga es este:

```
void cargar_n_datos(lista L,int cantv){
    int a=0;
    daots elem;
    printf("Ingrese la cantidad de datos a cargar\n");
    scanf("%d",&cant);
    while(cantv<1){
        printf("Ingrese una cantidad valida\n");
        scanf("%d",&cant);
    }
        if(!isfull(L)){
            while(a<cantv){
                reset(&L);
                cargar_datos_En_TDA(&elem);
                insertEnLista(L,cant);
                a++;
            }
        }
        else{
            printf("Espacio insuficiente. No se pudo cargar los datos");
            backwards(&L);
        }
}
```

La función que la pasa a la lista es esta:

```
void insert(lista L,int cantv){
     datos elem;
     if(!isfull(L)){
        reset(&L);
        while(!isoos(L)){
            insertar(&L,elem);
            forwards(&L);
        }
        printf("Carga exitosa\n");
    }
    else
        printf("Error. Los datos no pudieron cargarse\n");
}
```

**lista.h**:

```
typedef struct{
    datos VIPD;
    struct nodo *ps;
    struct nodo *pa;
}nodo;
typedef struct{
    nodo *acceso;
    nodo *cursor;
    nodo *cursoraux;
}listabi;
void inicializa(listabi *L){
    (*L).acceso=NULL;
    (*L).cursor=NULL;
}
int isempty(listabi L){
    if(L.acceso==NULL)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
int isfull(listabi L){
    nodo *n;
    if((n=(nodo*)malloc(sizeof(nodo)))==NULL)
        return 1;
    else{
        free(n);
        return 0;
    }
}
int isoos(listabi L){
    if(L.cursor==NULL)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
void reset(listabi *L){
    (*L).cursor=(*L).acceso;
}
void forwards(listabi *L){
    (*L).cursor=((*L).cursor)->ps;
}
void backwards(listabi *L){
    (*L).cursor=((*L).cursor)->pa;
}
void copia(listabi L){
    return L.cursor->VIPD;
}
void insertar(listabi *L,varados elem){
    nodo *p=(nodo*)malloc(sizeof(nodo));
    (*L).cursor->VIPD=elem;
    if((*L).acceso==NULL){
        (*L).acceso=p;
        (*p).ps=(*L).cursor;
        (*p).pa=NULL;
        (*L).cursor=p;
        (*L).cursoraux=p;
    }
    else{
       if((*L).acceso==(*L).cursor){
         (*L).acceso=p;
         (*p).ps=(*L).cursor;
         (*L).cursor->pa=p;
         (*p).pa=NULL;
       }
        else{
            if((*L).cursor!=NULL){
            (*p).ps=(*L).cursor;
            (*p).pa=(*L).cursoraux;
            (*L).cursor->pa=p;
            (*L).cursor=p;
            }
            else{
            (*p).ps=(*L).cursor;
            (*p).pa=(*L).cursoraux;
            (*L).cursoraux->ps=p;
            (*L).cursor=p;
            }
        }
    }
}
void suprimir(listabi *L, nodo *p){
    if((*L).acceso==(*L).cursor){
        (*L).acceso=((*L).cursor)->ps;
        free((*L).cursor);
        (*L).cursor=(*L).acceso;
        (*L).cursoraux=(*L).cursor;
    }
    else{
        if((*L).cursor!=NULL){
            (*L).cursoraux->ps=(*L).cursor->ps;
            free((*L).cursor);
            (*L).cursor=(*L).cursoraux->ps;
            (*L).cursor->pa=(*L).cursoraux;
        }
        else{
            (*L).cursoraux->ps=NULL;
            free((*L).cursor);
            (*L).cursor=(*L).cursoraux;
        }
    }
}
```

Función que carga datos en un *TDA*:

```
void cargar_datos(datos *D){
    char ape[20],nomb[20]
    long int documento;
    printf("Ingrese el apellido\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%[^\n]s",ape);
    cargar_apellido(&D,ape);
    printf("Ingrese el nombre\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%[^\n]s",nomb);
    cargar_nombre(&D,nomb);
    printf("Ingrese el documento\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%ld",&documento);
    cargar_documento(&D,documento);
}
```

¿Cómo lo soluciono?

Comment: ¿Cuál es la definición de `lista`, `daots` y `datos`?

Comment: En la edicion de la publicacion incluyo las definiciones del lista.h y la funcion que carga_datos_en_tda

Comment: esperaba que me dieran una respuesta de ayuda u.u

Comment: Creo que no actualizas correctamente el campo `cursoraux` con respecto de `cursor`. Pero en un principio, lo único que veo, que creo que es erróneo, es en la función `insertar`, ya que machacas el valor del nodo apuntado por el cursor en `(*L).cursor->VIPD = elem`, en lo que creo que intenabas hacer un `p->VIPD = elem`.

Comment: @MarcosPerez no te podemos dar una respuesta de ayuda frente a un código tan enrevesado del cuál no sabemos qué datos entras, cuales salen ni qué datos esperabas recibir. También faltan las definiciones de objetos que estás usando en el algoritmo. Deberías presentar un ejemplo mínimo que reproduzca el error.

Comment: ¿Te muestra algún mensaje de error?

Comment: En una parte dice `daots elem;` entonces está confundiéndose con `datos elem;`

Comment: También falta un punto y coma aquí. `char ape[20],nomb[20];`